# PHP + JavaScript: What happens behind scenes when comparing empty string to 0

Tags: javascript, php

Because of loose typing, PHP has to cast both compared variables to the same type, if they aren't yet. What happens behind the scenes for this comparison:

`$v = "" == 0;`

It returns `true`. If the type of the first variable is internally casted to the type of the second variable, I can understand it:

`$v = (int)"" === 0;`

But if it were so, the inverse comparison should fail:

`$w = 0 == "";`

because

`(string)0 = "0"`

which is obviously not equal to `""`.

but it returns `true`, as well.

The same behavior can be observed with JavaScript.

So now I am asking myself: what happens there?! The only explanation for me is that both variables are casted to boolean. But in this case, `["X"] == "X"` should return true, but it obviously doesn't. So, what's the magic to assume `""` equal `0`?

Comment: I know how to use `===` but I just wonder, which algorithm PHP follows for things like this. Your answer seems to be wrong, because `[] == ""` returns false, despite of both arguments being `empty()`.

Comment: That's just how PHP was designed, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP when using the equal it will convert the input so that the following are all equal:

```
0 == "" == false
```

Which all will pass an `empty()` check.

If you want to check the exact type use `===` instead. To answer your comment, array() is not a variable, but rather a data structure, that is why it fails the `==` check but passes the `empty()` check.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, the behavior of `==` is defined in [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

- When you do `"" == +0`, since `Type("")` is `String` and `Type(+0)` is `Number`, the returned value is the result of the comparison `ToNumber("") == +0`.

  The behaviour of applying `ToNumber` to `String` type is defined in [ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1). In our case, `ToNumber("")` returns `+0`.

  Now we must check `+0 == +0`. Since both have the same `Type`, that `Type` is `Number`, and both `+0` and `+0` have the same `Number` value, the returned value is `true`.
- When you do `+0 == ""`, since `Type(+0)` is `Number` and `Type("")` is `String`, the returned value is the result of the comparison `+0 == ToNumber("")`.

  The behaviour of applying `ToNumber` to `String` type is defined in [ToNumber Applied to the String Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1). In our case, `ToNumber("")` returns `+0`.

  Now we must check `+0 == +0`. Since both have the same `Type`, that `Type` is `Number`, and both `+0` and `+0` have the same `Number` value, the returned value is `true`.

Comment: ++ Didn't notice the question include javascript as well. Good explanation.

Comment: It's a pity, we can't accept two answers. This one is exactly as good as the Aziz' one, but it explains JS, and his one explains PHP. +1, however.

Answer (score 1):

php favors integers in comparisons, so if either value is an int the comparison will be done as an int.

The "int-ness" is determined not by type, but by an is_numeric() test.  Strings are silently converted to numbers even when you don't expect it, so "1.2" == "1.20" is true (!?).  Some versions of php used to say two long numeric strings were equal if they had an int overflow with idential prefixes.

Javascript seems to also cast to number when comparing to a number, but two strings compare as strings.